# Assembly : Convert 8 bit binary number to hexadecimal number

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need to write assembly program on tasm that needs to take for input: an 8 bit binary number and the output should be : hexadecimal representation of the same number.
example:
10010110 ->96
10110100 ->B4
Since i am very new in assembly,i don't have any idea from where i can start with solving that kind of problem.

edit : 
Here is my basic idea of how the program should be structured:

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100H

.DATA
  PROMPT_1  DB  'Enter the binary number : $'
  PROMPT_2  DB  0DH,0AH,'The number of 1 bits is : $'
  HEX_MAp   DB  '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F' 
  HEXA     DB      ?
.CODE
MAIN PROC
 MOV AX, @DATA                ; initialize DS  
 MOV DS, AX

 LEA DX, PROMPT_1             ; load and display PROMPT_1   
 MOV AH, 9
 INT 21H

 XOR BX, BX                   ; clear BX 
 MOV CX, 16                   ; initialize loop counter
 MOV AH, 1                    ; set input function
```

/
Ok,so after we load the `PROMT_1` variable which contains our binary number we need to separate it in 2 nibbles
(lets assume that our input is always correct 8 bit input)
i've found some guidence with google which states:

Imagine that you already have a binary number stored in register `ah` for exapmple 10101100

```
mov al, ah 
shr al, 4
```

so we have in `al` 00001010 
this is the first digit in hex form, if it's less thatn 10 you just output it in dec form, otherwise output the character (A, B, C, D, E, F)

next do the same with other 4 digits

```
mov al, ah 
shl al, 4 
shr al, 4
```

so we have in `al` 00001100 
and output the result

/

```
MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I need some guidance for the correct implementation here(i'm really not in the assembly syntax just yet,also the logic of the language is very untypical for me)

Comment: Have you tried reading up or following any tutorials on ASM? Is the Q about ASM or about converting binary to hexadecimal? If its the former then you can find similar answers. You should still attempt to show us what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yes i am developing some basic idea of what the code might look like(as i said before i am really not into assembly just yet)

Comment: @masss  How is the program supposed to receive the input ?  i.e., where does the program get the 8 bit value which it is to convert ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two main tasks:

1) to read a string from STDIN and to convert it in the computer format, an integer in a register, and

2) to convert the integer in a hexadecimal string and to output it.

It's easier for you to separate the tasks and handle them separatedly. For the second task there exist two common methods:

1) Read the hexadecimal character from a table (Example No. 1 in the following code). You need a table with 16 entries for each nibble. A nibble is a block of 4 bits. And yes: you could also create a table with 256 entries to handle a byte without "nibblifying" or a table with 65536 entries for a word (with some difficulties in 16-bit mode).

2) Calculate the ASCII code for each nibble (Example No. 2 in the following code).

I hope this code is helpful:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
  HEX_Map   DB  '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'
  HEX_Out   DB  "00", 13, 10, '$'   ; string with line feed and '$'-terminator

.CODE

main PROC
    mov ax, @DATA                   ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    ; Example No. 1 with output
    mov di, OFFSET HEX_Out          ; First argument: pointer
    mov ax, 10101100b               ; Second argument: Integer
    call IntegerToHexFromMap        ; Call with arguments
    mov ah, 09h                     ; Int 21h / 09h: Write string to STDOUT
    mov dx, OFFSET HEX_Out          ; Pointer to '$'-terminated string
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS

    ; Example No. 2 with output
    mov di, OFFSET HEX_Out          ; First argument: pointer
    mov ax, 10101100b               ; Second argument: Integer
    call IntegerToHexCalculated     ; Call with arguments
    mov ah, 09h                     ; Int 21h / 09h: Write string to STDOUT
    mov dx, OFFSET HEX_Out          ; Pointer to '$'-terminated string
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS

    mov ax, 4C00h                   ; Int 21h / 4Ch: Terminate program (Exit code = 00h)
    int 21h                         ; Call MS-DOS
main ENDP

IntegerToHexFromMap PROC
    mov si, OFFSET Hex_Map          ; Pointer to hex-character table

    mov bx, ax                      ; BX = argument AX
    and bx, 00FFh                   ; Clear BH (just to be on the safe side)
    shr bx, 4                       ; Isolate high nibble (i.e. 4 bits)
    mov dl, [si+bx]                 ; Read hex-character from the table
    mov [di+0], dl                  ; Store character at the first place in the output string

    mov bx, ax                      ; BX = argument AX (just to be on the safe side)
    and bx, 00FFh                   ; Clear BH (just to be on the safe side)
    and bl, 0Fh                     ; Isolate low nibble (i.e. 4 bits)
    mov dl, [si+bx]                 ; Read hex-character from the table
    mov [di+1], dl                  ; Store character at the second place in the output string

    ret
IntegerToHexFromMap ENDP

IntegerToHexCalculated PROC
    mov si, OFFSET Hex_Map          ; Pointer to hex-character table

    mov bx, ax                      ; BX = argument AX
    shr bl, 4                       ; Isolate high nibble (i.e. 4 bits)
    cmp bl, 10                      ; Hex 'A'-'F'?
    jl .1                           ; No: skip next line
    add bl, 7                       ; Yes: adjust number for ASCII conversion
    .1:
    add bl, 30h                     ; Convert to ASCII character
    mov [di+0], bl                  ; Store character at the first place in the output string

    mov bx, ax                      ; BX = argument AX (just to be on the safe side)
    and bl, 0Fh                     ; Isolate low nibble (i.e. 4 bits)
    cmp bl, 10                      ; Hex 'A'-'F'?
    jl .2                           ; No: skip next line
    add bl, 7                       ; Yes: adjust number for ASCII conversion
    .2:
    add bl, 30h                     ; Convert to ASCII character
    mov [di+1], bl                  ; Store character at the second place in the output string

    ret
IntegerToHexCalculated ENDP

END main                            ; End of assembly with entry-procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the byte into 2 nibbles, then use a 16-entry map to find the character.

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate the low nibble of the AL register we can simple use:

```
and al, 0Fh
```